# MySQL recursive update using triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

My goal is to design a schema without letting the user delete any rows, for this I made a column "inactive" for each table.

The problem is I have a list of tables designed like this.

```
sales_offers (so) -> sales_offers_items (soi) -> sales_offers_items_requisites (soir)
                                              -> sales_offers_items_labor (soil)
```

- `soir` & `soil` references `soi` with column `idparent`
- `soi`         refenrences `so` with column `idparent`

A short description of the tables:

- `so` - the header for a sale offer
- `soi` - contains the items offered
- `soir` - contains a list of items I need to build the item above (`soi`)
- `soil` - contains a list of labour costs per workshop

I have triggers on both `soir` & `soil` that do an update on their parent table `soi`. This update aggregates the values from each table and sums it up in the parent table so I can then use the aggregates to do some calculations.

My problem is this. When I set `so.inactive = 1` I want to recursively set `soi.inactive = 1; soir.inactive=1; soil.inactive=1`.

From what I understand MySQL does not let you design triggers this way so as to not do an infinite loop.

My only solution would be to use another table for the aggregation, something like `sales_offers_items_totals` (`soit`).

This solution would be too time consuming, I tried using composite foreign key, it works if I want to inactivate every child but if I want to inactivate only one row of a child table I get a constraint error.

If anyone has a better solution than the extra table for aggregations I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE so (so_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                  inactive  boolean);
> CREATE TABLE soi (soi_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                   inactive  boolean, 
>                   so_id INT, 
>                   FOREIGN KEY (so_id) REFERENCES so (so_id));
> CREATE TABLE soir (soir_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                    inactive  boolean, 
>                    soi_id INT, 
>                    FOREIGN KEY (soi_id) REFERENCES soi (soi_id));
> INSERT INTO so VALUES (11, 0), (111, 0);
> INSERT INTO soi VALUES (22, 0, 11), (222, 0, 111);
> INSERT INTO soir VALUES (33, 0, 22), (333, 0, 222);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_so
> AFTER UPDATE
> ON so
> FOR EACH ROW
> UPDATE soi SET inactive = NEW.inactive WHERE so_id = NEW.so_id;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER tr_au_soi
> AFTER UPDATE
> ON soi
> FOR EACH ROW
> UPDATE soir SET inactive = NEW.inactive WHERE soi_id = NEW.soi_id;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM so;
> SELECT * FROM soi;
> SELECT * FROM soir;
> SELECT * 
> FROM so
> JOIN soi USING (so_id)
> JOIN soir USING (soi_id);
> ```
>
> ```
> so_id | inactive
> ----: | -------:
>    11 |        0
>   111 |        0
>
> soi_id | inactive | so_id
> -----: | -------: | ----:
>     22 |        0 |    11
>    222 |        0 |   111
>
> soir_id | inactive | soi_id
> ------: | -------: | -----:
>      33 |        0 |     22
>     333 |        0 |    222
>
> soi_id | so_id | inactive | inactive | soir_id | inactive
> -----: | ----: | -------: | -------: | ------: | -------:
>     22 |    11 |        0 |        0 |      33 |        0
>    222 |   111 |        0 |        0 |     333 |        0
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE so SET inactive = 1 WHERE so_id = 11;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM so;
> SELECT * FROM soi;
> SELECT * FROM soir;
> SELECT * 
> FROM so
> JOIN soi USING (so_id)
> JOIN soir USING (soi_id);
> ```
>
> ```
> so_id | inactive
> ----: | -------:
>    11 |        1
>   111 |        0
>
> soi_id | inactive | so_id
> -----: | -------: | ----:
>     22 |        1 |    11
>    222 |        0 |   111
>
> soir_id | inactive | soi_id
> ------: | -------: | -----:
>      33 |        1 |     22
>     333 |        0 |    222
>
> soi_id | so_id | inactive | inactive | soir_id | inactive
> -----: | ----: | -------: | -------: | ------: | -------:
>     22 |    11 |        1 |        1 |      33 |        1
>    222 |   111 |        0 |        0 |     333 |        0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec18df23c161a5d66d51ffc459d9fa55)*

Comment: Hi Akina, thanks for the answer. I did all this. The problem is that soir has a trigger on column 'value'  that does an update on soi.total_value. When I update soi.inactive and start the trigger mysql says that i cannot update this table because it is being used in another trigger/function.